# how to find number of white spaces in a line after a string in HTML textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, textarea, whitespace

I have a text area and a button. I am appending some String(text) in textarea with the every onclick() of the button.

The String should be one line or half line or two line whatever it may be.

But I need to know the remaining white spaces in the line after the string.I am going to do some stuff if I got the solution for the question.

If the question is not understand or having any doubts please ask me to explain it .

Comment: @peru  I am doing the chat application.message will be displayed in textarea when I press the button.That are all working fine.Now i need to append the current time with the every messages at the right side corner of textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
yourTextarea.value.split( '\n' ).map( function( str ) { 
    var ws = str.match( /\s+$/g )
    return ws ? ws[ 0 ].length : 0;
});
```

will output a number of ending white spaces for each line, like:

```
[0, 3, 4]
```

Comment: it shows the script error as " object doesn't supported this property or method " .??? what I do ?

Comment: `var yourTextarea = document.getElementById( 'idOfYourTextarea' );`